# MVC optional route parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to be able to navigate to `/orders/show`, `/orders/show/10`, and `orders/show/10/20`, for example. I tried the following:

```
    [Route("orders/show/{skip=0:int:min(0)?}/{take=10:int:min(0)?}")]
    public ActionResult Show(int? skip, int? take)
    {
        var inventory = ApplicationDbContext.Orders.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip(skip.Value).Take(take.Value).ToList();

        return View(inventory);
    }
```

Basically, the goal is to build a table listing orders 1-10, 11-20, etc. Unless I input all parameters, I get a 404 Not found exception.

Comment: rather doing things here do this in routeconfig file..

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla This example is using `Attribute Routing`. Which you cannot "do" in the `RouteConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

You ned to register the route in the routeconfig file. e.g. In the AppStart folder, go to routeconfig and register you route. e.g.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Orders",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Orders", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    }
```